# mongoid 'exists' don't work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

Hi am trying out a query and is giving me strange results. I am trying to get a list of object where a field doesn't exist with a where clause added to it.

Step one the where clause:

```
ContentMirror.where(source: 'some_source').count
```

This query returns 9984 records.
`some_source` have a field call `vid_emded_obj` which I know some are `nil` For example:

```
ContentMirror.find('50fff286781200986e000ae3')
=> #<ContentMirror _id: 50fff286781200986e000ae3, _type: nil, created_at: 2012-12-15 13:12:22 UTC, updated_at: 2013-01-29 12:10:23 UTC, deleted_at: nil, title: "Introduction to Polynomials", vid_emded_obj: nil, media_type: "video", source: "some_source", thumbnail_url: nil, md5: "459173975a7fb145b3ca8b99e1c2ae78">
```

So I was expecting that at lest that count of 1 will return if I do this:

```
ContentMirror.where(source: 'some_source').exists(vid_emded_obj: false).count
=> 0
```

Cannot work out why...

Answer (score 0):

I belkieve that exists checks if the property is there at all, and will return true if the value of that property is empty.
I will just go hunt for the doc to confirm :)

EDIT:

So, the doc does not mention any exists(...).
Only an exists? method that can be applied on a criteria.

I think you should do  (pseudo code, I haven't tried it)

```
ContentMirror.count(vid_embed_obj:nil, source: 'some_source')
```

or

```
ContentMirror.where(vid_embed_obj:nil, source: 'some_source').count
```

or again

```
ContentMirror.excludes(vid_embed_obj:nil).where(source: 'some_source').count
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans. I got the doc from here: http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html

Comment: I tried with all 2 of them (first one dont work). They all returned a count of 9984 which is the same as if I counted without the vid_embed_obj field.

Comment: does the documents contain a field vid_embed_obj? or is this field simply not part of the document?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Stephane vid_embed_obj does exist as a field is just nil for 'some_source' but not nil for 'other_source'